# In RSpec, what's the difference between before(:suite) and before(:all)?

Tags: rspec, rspec2

[The before and after hook documentation on Relish](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-13/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks) only shows that `before(:suite)` is called prior to `before(:all)`.

When should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

When a `before(:all)` is defined in the `RSpec.configure` block it is called before each top level example group, while a `before(:suite)` code block is only called once.

Here's an example:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:all) { puts 'Before :all' }
  config.after(:all) { puts 'After :all' }
  config.before(:suite) { puts 'Before :suite' }
  config.after(:suite) { puts 'After :suite' }
end

describe 'spec1' do
  example 'spec1' do
    puts 'spec1'
  end
end

describe 'spec2' do
  example 'spec2' do
    puts 'spec2'
  end
end
```

Output:

```
Before :suite
Before :all
spec1
After :all
Before :all
spec2
After :all
After :suite
```

Comment: my question is: "If I load some seed data like admin User using `before suite` wont that data be cleared after example is run?"

Comment: No they will stay, you have to deal with them manually. Only before(:example) is inside transaction.

Comment: :suite and :context (= :all) are outside transaction. No matter how deep are contexts nested.

Answer (score 0):

> You can also use before(:suite) to run a block of code before any
>   example groups are run. This should be declared in RSpec.configure

http://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Hooks

Comment: I'm observing how a guy that was working at my position before me, misunderstood the "This should be declared in `RSpec.configure`" and has put all his pre-run fixtures into `RSpec.configure` -- they now run even with `--dry-run`. I'm told "to not touch anything! only add new tests"...

Comment: This was 2013, the answer is probably irrelevant anyway.